# How to change Toolbar text style to custom from manifest?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am setting toolbar tittle from the manifest file using `android:label="Setting"`.

What I want is to set a custom font form asset folder.

```
<activity android:name=".Testingtoolbars"
            android:label="Setting">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is my **toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Below is my Activity:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testingtoolbars);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

I don't want to use a custom toolbar like this:

```
 <Toolbar>
    <TextView>
    </TextView>
 </Toolbar>
```

Comment: as per my opinion better ti use  custom toolbar

Comment: @NileshRathod due do some reason i want like that only sir

Answer (score 1):

1) Define a theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/fancy-font</item>
```

2) Set that theme in your Toolbars layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>
```

for older version support try :

```
toolbar.findViewsWithText(outViews, title, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
if (!outViews.isEmpty()) {
    final TextView titleView = (TextView) outViews.get(0);

    final Toolbar.LayoutParams layoutParams = (Toolbar.LayoutParams) 
    titleView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    titleView.setTypeface(Typeface);
    toolbar.requestLayout();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: fontfamily is not working it working from api level above 26

Comment: Add textView inside Toolbar then set fontFamily to textView.